# Mark questions for easy access in future

Tags: support

I want to mark some questions so that they are collected somewhere in my profile, so that I can view them easily later.

Also I don't want to favorite the question as not every question that I want to mark are good (I mean some time I need to address someone that using a wrong way can cause the damage as described)

Is there any way to do so? If not would love to see in future.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrr :=D

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this, if favorites doesn't work for you then just bookmark the page in your browser!

Comment: I think I understant what are you talkning about I have more than 70 or 80 or 90 or ...or 100000000 favorate question and do not know  how search in them :( :( :( also I think it is better to vote

Answer (score 7):

- Making it a favorite does not mark it as good. good would mean upvotes and for an answer an accepted mark.
- If a question or answer is wrong feel free to comment or even edit the question (when priviliges allow it).